# Bootstrap Glyphicon-search button size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm having trouble resizing the search button so that it will be the same height as the textfield. Thank you in advance!.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="search" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Input Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) instead of Input Group Addon and change the button to match the input size of small. See example Snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="search" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /input-group -->
```